# BigQuery: (backup) copy of sharded Google Analytics tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

When Google Analytics is exported to BigQuery, the data is put in so called sharded tables, one for each day. They all start with `ga_sessions_` followed by the suffix of a date.

I want to make a backup copy of these sharded tables.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer relates to creating the backup in BQ:

So a sharded table such as `ga_sessions_` basically exists of many tables, one for each day. We need to copy all those tables separately.

The below answer is a copy from the article below and all respect goes to the author:
https://medium.com/@Nayana22/playing-with-sharded-tables-in-bigquery-123e1ec5e453

So you can do as follows:

1. Take the list of all the days that you wish to copy by hitting below SQL command. [You can modify this as per your need]

```sql
SELECT
REPLACE(STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', partition_name,'"') ORDER BY partition_name ), ","," ")
FROM 
(
  SELECT
  DISTINCT date AS partition_name
  FROM
  `[Project_ID].[DATASET_NAME].ga_sessions_*`
  ORDER BY PARSE_DATE(“%Y%m%d”, date)
)

Output:
"20180322" "20180323" "20180324" "20180325" "20180326" "20180327"...
```

2. Now, go to google console, select the project and click on Activate Cloud Shell.
3. Check the current project using echo $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID. If you’re in an incorrect project then change it and move to step 4.
4. Create a bash script and specify the days that you just got from the above query.

```sh
tables=(“20180322” “20180323” “20180324” “20180325” “20180326” “20180327”…)
```

5. Iterate through all the days available in tables variable and use BigQuery’s copy command to move a table from source to destination.
   Syntax: [Note: There is a space between the source and destination table name]

```sh
bq cp -a source_table destination_table
```

6. Our, script file looks like this:

```sh
tables=("20180322" "20180323" "20180324" "20180325" "20180326" "20180327"…)
for val in ${tables[*]}; do
  bq cp -a [source_dataset].ga_sessions_$val [destination_dataset].ga_sessions_backup_$val
done
```

7. How to validate whether all the tables are copied or not?

```sql
WITH first_ga_session AS (
   SELECT MIN(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", REGEXP_EXTRACT(table_id, '20[0–9]      
   {6,6}'))) AS day
   FROM `[PROJECT_ID].[DATASET_NAME].__TABLES__` AS ga_tables
   WHERE table_id LIKE 'ga_sessions_backup_2%'
),
all_days AS (
   SELECT period
   FROM 
   UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY((SELECT day from first_ga_session),              
   CURRENT_DATE())) AS period
),
available_ga_sessions AS (
   SELECT PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", REGEXP_EXTRACT(table_id, '20[0–9]
   {6,6}')) AS ga_day
   FROM `[PROJECT_ID].[DATASET_NAME].__TABLES__` AS ga_tables
   WHERE table_id LIKE 'ga_sessions_backup_2%'
)
SELECT A.period AS Day, B.ga_day AS Available_session
FROM all_days A
LEFT JOIN available_ga_sessions B
ON A.period = B.ga_day
WHERE B.ga_day IS NULL
```

The above query will give us all the days that are missing in the destination table.

My bash script ended up looking like this (note i'm using cloning with flag `--clone`:

```sh
tables=("20220331" "20220401")

bq --location=eu mk --dataset destination_project_id:destination_dataset

for val in ${tables[*]}; do
  echo source_project_id:source_dataset.ga_sessions_$val
  bq cp --clone source_project_id:source_dataset.ga_sessions_$val destination_project_id:destination_dataset.ga_sessions_backup_$val

done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to backup the tables to a Cloud Storage Bucket you can try the following.

1. Query [table meta data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) to get the tables to export.

```sql
SELECT
  table_name
FROM
  `MyDataSet.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
WHERE
  table_name LIKE 'ga_sessions_%'
```

2. Use the [BigQuery export function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement) to export the to the bucket.

```sql
-- If the tables are nested use json/avro/parquet
-- But be aware of the data type converstions:
-- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in

EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://bucket/folder/ga_sessions_<date>_*.json',
  format='JSON', 
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT * FROM mydataset.ga_sessions_<date>
```

3. Put it together in a [BQ script](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting-concepts) with a loop, using [FORMAT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string) to create the query and [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) to run the query.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE backup_date STRING DEFAULT CAST(CURRENT_DATE('UTC') AS STRING);

FOR record IN
  (
    SELECT
        table_name
    FROM
        `MyDataSet.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
    WHERE
        table_name LIKE 'ga_sessions_%')
DO
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        FORMAT("""    
            EXPORT DATA
            OPTIONS(
                uri=CONCAT('gs://your_backup_bucket/path/to/folder/', '%s','/', '%s','_*.json'),
                format='JSON',
                overwrite=true,
                header=true,
                field_delimiter=';')
            AS SELECT * FROM my_project.my_data_set.%s
        """ 
        , backup_date, record.table_name, record.table_name);

END FOR;
END;
```

- `backup_date` is used to create a 'folder' with the export date as a name in the bucket for the tables.
- The `*` in the URI allows a table to be exported into multiple tables. This only matters if the exported table is bigger than 1GB ([See here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations))
- Set a life cycle rule on your storage bucket to archive files after an appropriate time or set it to archive by default if it's only for backup purposes (Accessed less once a year, see [storage classes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes)).

Props to Tim Lou for [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/big-query-hack-flexible-queries-for-any-number-of-columns-713fa0c6f6a5) on using table meta data.